# How to count the occurence of each term in a single column of a flat file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the following flat file `employees.txt`

```
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales       $5,000
200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500
300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000
400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500
500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
```

I want to count the amount of people in each department.  I know there are shorter ways to do this using a command like `awk '{print $4}' employees.txt | sort | uniq -c` but I want to learn the mechanics of a while loop, reading the input line-by-line

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{print $4}' employees.txt > temp_file

array=[]
while read line
do
        if [[ $array[$line] ]]
        then
                $array[$line]=$(($array[$line]+1))
        else
                $array[$line]=0
        fi
done < temp_file
```

When I run this script I get the error `./process.sh: line 9: [][Sales]+1: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[][Sales]+1")`

Also - is there a syntax I could use after the `done` keyword to grab the entries in the fourth column? I tried `done < awk '{print $4}' employees.txt` but that was incorrect.

Also - is there a way I could store the output of `awk '{print $4}' employees.txt > temp_file` in a variable instead of a temporary file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{print $4}' employees.txt > temp_file
declare -A array
while read line
do
        if [[ ${array["$line"]} ]]; then
          array["$line"]=$(( ${array["$line"]} + 1 ))
        else
          array["$line"]=1
        fi
done < temp_file

for k in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "$k ${array[$k]}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you explain what the dollar sign, braces syntax means in regards to the array?

Comment: Dolar sign and braces means you are going to refer to a variable. Then you can write the array name and index. Otherwise bash tries to substitute the name and concat it with `[...]` stuff so you get `$array` and `[index]` separately.

Answer (score 1):

The use of awk is not required. You could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash       # bash 4
declare -A DEPARTMENT
while read -a field
do
  (( DEPARTMENT[${field[3]}]++ ))
done < employees.txt

for dep in "${!DEPARTMENT[@]}"
do
  printf "%s\n" "$dep ${DEPARTMENT[$dep]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array=[]
```

is not correct. Bash array is declared like this

```
declare -A array=()
```

or perhaps just

```
array=()
```

> Also - is there a syntax I could use after the done keyword to grab the entries in the
>   fourth column? I tried `done < awk '{print $4}' employees.txt`

You can try process substitution

```
done < <(awk '{print $4}' employees.txt)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same syntax error even after making that change.  Thanks for the tip on process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, the first in `bash` (which is similar to, but more concise than the other given solutions - eliminating the use of `awk` to pull out the forth column, instead using `read`).

First, the `bash` implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -A dept
while read -r _ _ _ d _; do
   ((dept[$d]++))
done <<-'!'
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales       $5,000
200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500
300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000
400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500
500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
!

for d in "${!dept[@]}"; do
   printf '%s %d\n' "$d" "${dept[$d]}"
done
```

The `awk` implementation is very similar:

```
awk '
   {
      dept[$4]++;
   }
   END {
      for (d in dept)
         print d, dept[d]
   }
' <<'!'
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales       $5,000
200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500
300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000
400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500
500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
!
```